Add-ons / plugins for android or ios applications
Suppose I have an application for both android or ios which has splash screen containing earth image and launcher icon and app name and all other fetaures to show contents regarding particular continents. Now I want to make customized application for 5 continents to show their corresponding contents only with customizations as their own map on the splash screen and own name of the app and own launcher icon.
Now the thing is I don't want to create 5 different application and upload them on the google play console or app store seperately. I have one base application where all the necessary fetures are there and 5 different add-ons available for each continents.
Now how can I build these applications where all the 6 applications are displayed seperately and user have to install the base app and then install the customized one from the same publisher i.e. play store or app store? And then they will only show their continent's contents. So that the app override splash resources image, app name and launcher icon whenever the user install any customized application with the base application?
And how the application is displayed in the android or ios device whethere they are shown as different applications or the base application overrides the property of the customized app. I want this as just like add-on or plugins architectures.
Here is the Solid Explorer App and it has plugins and when you install the plugins then the plugin is not visible in the app list but also enhance the feature of the base application. This is what I want to install some resources by intalling the different plugins as shown in the image.

